# When generating an XML file with Go, how do you create a doctype declaration?

Tags: xml, go, doctype

Go's `xml` package is excellent and makes dealing with XML very easy.  There's one thing I'm not sure how to do: when creating an XML document from a native struct, how do you specify the doctype?

For example, these structs:

```
type Person struct {
    XMLName    xml.Name `xml:"person"`
    FirstName  string   `xml:"firstName"`
    MiddleName string   `xml:"middleName"`
    LastName   string   `xml:"lastName"`
    Age        int64    `xml:"age"`
    Skills     []Skill  `xml:"skills"`
}

type Skill struct {
    XMLName        xml.Name `xml:"skill"`
    Name           string   `xml:"skillName"`
    YearsPracticed int64    `xml:"practice"`
}
```

Will generate something like this XML:

```
<person>
    <firstName>Bob</firstName>
    <middleName></middleName>
    <lastName>Jones</middleName>
    <age>23</age>
    <skills>
        <skill>
            <skillName>Cooking</skillName>
            <practice>3</practice>
        </skill>
        <skill>
            <skillName>Basketball</skillName>
            <practice>4</practice>
        </skill>
    </skills>
</person>
```

Which is great, but what do I do to get this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<person>
    <firstName>Bob</firstName>
    <middleName></middleName>
    ...
```

It almost seems *too* simple, but is this a matter of doing a string append?

And, on the reverse, how would Go's XML parser handle a doctype in a block of text that you wanted to unmarshal into a set of structs?  Ignore it?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Simply append your marshalled bytes to the header. As seen in the [XML Package Source](http://golang.org/pkg/encoding/xml#pkg-constants), a generic header is included:

```
const (
    // A generic XML header suitable for use with the output of Marshal.
    // This is not automatically added to any output of this package,
    // it is provided as a convenience.
    Header = `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>` + "\n"
)
```

So, this would do it:

```
myString, err := xml.MarshalIndent(...) // abbreviated here
myString = []byte(xml.Header + string(myString))
```

A working example I'd found (not my code) available at: http://play.golang.org/p/Rbfb717tvh

Comment: Thanks, I'd overlooked this in the package source.  Any data on how the header is handled during Unmarshaling?

Comment: I imagine you might be able to collect it, since looking at the source briefly shows that they are parsing `<?` prefix tags; I'm not sure what the required struct tag would be. Maybe 'xml'.

Comment: Since converting to and fro between `[]byte` and `string` involves memory copying, it is unfortunate that such a thing is necessary. `myString` could be very large after all.

Answer (score 7):

Another approach that might worth mentioning here is the one that uses the native [XML encoders from Go](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/xml/#Encoder), which are more suitable than the common `marshal` function when dealing with streams of XML, or when you plan to work with pretty large XML files.

In this case you would follow a similar approach by creating the struct objects you want to encode first, but now the 2nd step will be creating the `*File` reference and then writing the [`xml.Header`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/xml/#pkg-constants) to it:

```
xmlFile, err := os.Create("my-file.xml")
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println("Error creating XML file: ", err)
    return
}
xmlFile.WriteString(xml.Header)
```

After that you will need to create your XML encoder, set up its indentation, and finally encoding the necessary structs into the XML file:

```
encoder := xml.NewEncoder(xmlFile)
encoder.Indent("", "\t")
err = encoder.Encode(&myStruct)
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println("Error encoding XML to file: ", err)
    return
}
```

You should see the resulting XML file with the document header you want after that.

Here is a quick POF by using the samples you provided:

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/xml"
    "fmt"
    "os"
)

// Person represents a <person> node in the XML
type Person struct {
    XMLName    xml.Name `xml:"person"`
    FirstName  string   `xml:"firstName"`
    MiddleName string   `xml:"middleName"`
    LastName   string   `xml:"lastName"`
    Age        int64    `xml:"age"`
    Skills     []Skill  `xml:"skills"`
}

// Skill represents a <skill> node in the XML
type Skill struct {
    XMLName        xml.Name `xml:"skill"`
    Name           string   `xml:"skillName"`
    YearsPracticed int64    `xml:"practice"`
}

func main() {
    person := Person{
        FirstName:  "Bob",
        MiddleName: "",
        LastName:   "Jones",
        Age:        23,
        Skills: []Skill{
            {
                Name:           "Cooking",
                YearsPracticed: 3,
            },
            {
                Name:           "Basketball",
                YearsPracticed: 4,
            },
        },
    }

    xmlFile, err := os.Create("person.xml")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Error creating XML file: ", err)
        return
    }
    xmlFile.WriteString(xml.Header)
    encoder := xml.NewEncoder(xmlFile)
    encoder.Indent("", "\t")
    err = encoder.Encode(&person)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Error encoding XML to file: ", err)
        return
    }
}
```

And this will generate the following XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<person>
    <firstName>Bob</firstName>
    <middleName></middleName>
    <lastName>Jones</lastName>
    <age>23</age>
    <skill>
        <skillName>Cooking</skillName>
        <practice>3</practice>
    </skill>
    <skill>
        <skillName>Basketball</skillName>
        <practice>4</practice>
    </skill>
</person>
```